# Stop Apache from decoding characters from URI for PATH_INFO

Tags: php, apache-2.4, symfony

I want to stop Apache from decoding `%2B` (`+`) and `%3D` (`=`) from URI. I need those chars not decoded in PATH_INFO.

I've did that for `%2F` (`/`) by using:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

But, I can't find any directive(s) that could help me do the same for other encoded characters. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent Apache from decoding those %-encoded characters in the `PATH_INFO` Apache server variable (which PHP assigns later to the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` superglobal, seemingly unaltered).

The `AllowEncodedSlashes` directive is a special case. This is really a "security feature". By default, an encoded slash (`%2F`) in the path-part of the URL triggers a *system generated* 404 response. The `AllowEncodedSlashes` directive allows the request to get through to the application (the `NoDecode` option was only added later).

If you want to read the %-encoded `PATH_INFO` in PHP then consider using a different `$_SERVER` variable instead, such as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, which is not %-decoded, but this will require some additional parsing. (Note that the PHP superglobal `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is different from the Apache server variable of the same name, which is %-decoded and could refer to a different URL entirely if the URL is being rewritten!)

However, if you want to read the %-encoded `PATH_INFO` with Apache (using mod_rewrite) then consider parsing the `THE_REQUEST` server variable instead, which contains the entire request header, as sent from the client. This variable is not %-decoded. This could be assigned to an environment variable or even a URL parameter and read by PHP that way. (Note that the `QUERY_STRING` server variable, and corresponding `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` superglobal, are not %-decoded, but PHP decodes the individual parameter values in the `$_GET` array.)

Comment: I think you meant `@_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` in your second line?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thanks, yes, that's what I meant! Now corrected.